# How to make Android in-app notifications stackable?

Tags: java, android, notifications, stack

I have an Android app in kiosk mode in which I would like to send notifications to the users if necessary.

At first I was using the `Toast` but then I made a `FlashMessage` class (extending `Snackbar`) so that i could personalize (error/success/warning...). It might not be the best way but it works nice.

The only thing is `Toast` and `Snackbar` are not stackable.  So if I call more than one `FlashMessage` in a row, the previous one is replaced by the new one and the message is lost.

Is there a (easy) way to make it stackable (I didn't see a option in the doc) or maybe to use another class to make something similar?

(I am using mostly java/kotlin)

push notification are not working since the app is in kiosk mode.

`Toast` and `Snackbar` work nice but don't stack.